# Confusion over Notation and definition relating to concept for $p$-group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In the section of Finite Abelian groups, the following notation definition and notation comes up in the context preceding the definition of $p-groups$.

> If $G$ is an abelian group and $p$ is a prime, then $G(p)$ denotes the set of elements in $G$ whose order is some power of $p$, that is

$$G(p)=\{a\in G: |a|=p^{n} \text{ for some } n\geq 0\}$$.

Example:  If $G=\mathbb{Z}_{12}$, then $G(2)$ is the set of elements having orders $2^{0}, 2^1, 2^2,$ etc.   Verify that $G(2)$ is the subgroup $\{0,3,6,9\}$; similarly, $G(3)=\{0,4,8\}$.

I have two question about them:

Question 1:  What is $G(p)$ called in the literature. 
Question 2:  I am having trouble understanding how $G(2)$ is the subgroup $\{0,3,6,9\}$.

My understanding is, $G(2)=\{a\in G: |a|=2^{n} \text{ for some } n\geq 0\}$ and assuming that we are talking about an additive operation for $G=\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ and we are not finding the inverse elements for each $a$.  Then:

$|a|=2^{0},$ $a=0$
$|a|=2^{1},$ $a=6$
$|a|=2^{2},$ $a=3$
$|a|=2^{n},$ $a=9$, for which $n$?
$\vdots$
$etc$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It is more commonly denoted $G\{p\}$ (but notations do vary), and is usually called the "$p$-primary subgroup" or "$p$-primary part" of $G$.

Comment: Also $a=1$ does is not in $G(2)$, it has order $12$ which is not a power of $2$. You probably meant $a=0$.

Comment: @CaptainLama I still don't understand the example, how is $G(2)$ the subgroup {0,3,6,9}.  I just can't figure out what value for $n$ is $a=9$.

Comment: @CaptainLama, yes, that is what I meant.  Thank you for pointing it out

Comment: What is the smallest $m$ such that $9m$ is dividible by $12$?

Comment: @CaptainLama $m=4$.  Wait, the $a$'s are not suppose to equal to the $n$'s?  Am I not understanding the definition correctly?

Comment: I think you are not understanding what $|a|$ means: it is the order of $a$ in $G$, so the minimal $m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m\cdot a=0$. Admittedly, this is not a very standard notation. But the order of $9$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ is not $3$: $3\cdot 9=27$ is not dividible by $12$.

Comment: @CaptainLama I made the correction.  I think I understand now.  Thank you for your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In view of the 2nd question, your group $G=\Bbb Z_{12}$ is written additively and so
$G(2) = \{a\in G\mid m\cdot a = 0, m=2^n \mbox{ for some }n\geq 0\}$.

Here $4\cdot 3 = 0$, $2\cdot 6=0$, and $4\cdot 9 = 0$.

Comment: thank for for the clarification.   :)